# How to achieve Polling a table every some seconds using multithreading/threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, polling, scheduledexecutorservice

I have a requirement where I need to poll a table every 5 seconds. If there is a new entry with a specific status flag, then I'll have to process it and create a report using JasperReports, and once the process is done, I'll have to update the status as done.

We need to implement multithreading, where if one thread polls and finds a new record, it starts processing it and generates the report.

If this processing takes more than 5 seconds, only another thread should poll the table and pick if a record is present. If the first thread is busy processing for more than 5 seconds, then 2nd thread jumps in, if the 2nd thread gets busy for more than 5 seconds, then the 3rd thread can pitch in, so we need thread pool as well. But two threads can poll the table in a time difference of 5 seconds.

Overall, the table should be polled only once in 5 seconds.

Comment: _I need to poll a table_ Is that a database table?

Comment: The solution would be dependent on the environment, for instance multi deployment. However, assuming a single deployment, the design should factor in 1 thread for polling no more, multi-thread polling scenarios are slightly uncommon. The design should be for 1 thread to poll and a thread pool to process the result of the polling where a BlockingQueue (usually) inbetween with a dispatcher thread to dispatch to the executor(possibley a thread pool executor). Many other design perspectives are possible, i am highlighting a simplistic one.